# List current existing or applied key bindings made via bindkey

Tags: zsh

My ZSH has at some point been told to bind <kbd>Delete</kbd> to some complicated function, key sequence, or macro, and I want to remove this binding from my configuration. In order to better find where this binding is being set, I'd like to see what Zsh is actually doing when I hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

How can I see a list of all the currently existing key bindings present in my Zsh environment?

Answer (score 8):

Just run `bindkey` with no arguments:

```
$ bindkey
"^A"-"^C" self-insert
"^D" list-choices
"^E"-"^F" self-insert
"^G" list-expand
"^H" vi-backward-delete-char
"^I" expand-or-complete
"^J" history-substring-search-down
"^K" self-insert
"^L" clear-screen
...
```

However, the particular behavior you are describing with regards to  <kbd>Delete</kbd> can be resolved by adding this to your `.zshrc`:

```
bindkey    "^[[3~"          delete-char
bindkey    "^[3;5~"         delete-char
```

## Explanation

Depending on the terminal, <kbd>Delete</kbd> generates one of the following character sequences:

- `^[[3~`
- `^[3;5~`

You can see which sequence your terminal uses via `sed -n l` as [explained here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76591/4143).

`zsh` tries to evaluate the longest match. In both cases, `zsh` matches `^[` first, which matches <kbd>Esc</kbd>. If you have `vi` mode enabled, this tells `zsh` to turn it on.

After this, `vi` mode reads the remaining characters, which are one of the following:

- `[3~` toggle the case of the next 3 characters
- `3;5~` repeat the last find operation 3 times then toggle the case of the next 5 characters

So if you haven't explicitly used `bindkey` on this character sequence, every time you press <kbd>Delete</kbd> with `vi` mode enabled, you will enter `vi` mode and the last character you typed will be uppercased.

<sup>Thanks to [Adaephon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2992551/adaephon) in the comments below for help with this explanation.</sup>

Comment: It is actually the opposite of a "built-in". In the *vi* modes (`viins` and `vicmd`) the character sequences `^[[3~` and `^[3;5~` are not defined as a whole. In this case `zsh` will evaluate the longest possible parts. In this case it finds either the sequence `^[`, `[` and `3~`, or the sequence `^[`, `3;`, `5~`, depending on the terminal. `^[` is Escape and switches into `vicmd` or beeps. Any further bindings are now in `vicmd`: `[` has no binding, `3~` toggles the case of the next 3 characters, `3;` repeats the last find operation 3 times and `5~` toggles the case of 5 characters.

Comment: @Adaephon Would you mind if I add that information to the answer, attributing you? That is super interesting. My "built-in" explanation came from some minor Googling, but now the weird behavior I was seeing on the Delete key actually makes sense after reading your explanation.